# Controller method is called but there is no code in the controller

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, controller

So here is a problem, during past few months I have been working on my Masters Project and haven't used source control. The project does big data calculation and requires a lot of RAM, therefore sometimes a laptop works really slow or stops responding and then I have to reboot it.

I wrote all the code in controller of my MVC Project. After my last force reboot, my controller has all nulls and does not show any previous code that I have written. In the same way, my app works fine and controller methods are revoked properly.

[image: Controller does not even have an expansion link]

When I click on controller VS opens an empty notepad document instead of controller code. Unfortunately, I haven't used source control and don't have a build. Any help is highly appreciated.

Here are the files that I have in by `debug` folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to face this kind of situation in future, please back up your data or use source control. If you were not careful like me and did the same mistake, then here is the solution:

1. Go to your project folder
2. Go to `/YourProject/YourProject.Web/obj/Debug`
3. Find `YourProject.Web.dll`
4. Go to `https://jetbrains.com/decompiler`and download `.dll` decompiler
5. Install decompiler and restore `.dll` to a project
6. Go to restored project folder->Controllers->RestoredController.cs

Once you open `RestoredController.cs` you will find the code you lost.